# Is qualityMosaic the same as MVC (max value composite)?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, ndvi

I want to make an annual Landsat 5 image for area A in Google Earth Engine using MVC. The growing season in this area is from April to August.

1. I get data from April to October.
2. I masked the clouds.
3. I calculated the NDVI value.
4. I used `qualityMosaic`.
5. I extracted the NDVI band and named it as the Annual Data.

The problem is, the Annual NDVI chart I got is very strange.

[image]

[image]

From literature, and according to my knowledge, the NDVI peak in area A is in June and July. I assume that I made some mistakes in my data process, but I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the `qualityMosaic` function with `NDVI` band as the quality band in a manner similar to

```
var mosaic = myImageCollection.qualityMosaic('NDVI')
```

assuming the `NDVI` calculation was correct, the clouds, cloud shadows, and atmospheric effects were appropriately dealt with, then your mosaic is maximum-value composite based on the `NDVI` band.

There could be several reasons why the `NDVI` time-series is not showing the peak values where you want them to:

1. The location of the extracted pixels are not in a vegetated area or there is some mixing.
2. If you are taking some area statistic for `NDVI` time-series, then maybe its not a homogeneous land-cover type in that area.
3. The vegetation characteristics are different in that particular location than the accepted knowledge.
4. The assumptions are incorrect and there is some pre-processing step that is missing or incomplete.

Comment: Thank you very much. I rechecked my code, but I found no mistakes. I think I extracted the non-vegetated pixel.